# Vote UP Vote UP Vote UP

Tags: discussion

Trying to push this up --

As the site is still in beta, I think that we need to vote up more and increase the number of users with privileges.

I am not asking to vote up on any question, or comment, but in general, I see many questions with very low number or even 0 votes. If a question deserved a comment or an answer, it certainly deserves a vote up.

This serves both for the site, to have more privileged users, but also for the user itself, as it increases his reputation, and gives him more positive push/feedback.

Comment: Up-voted. ;-) but yeah, I agree.

Comment: Definitely.  If you read a question and there is an answer that you know is the best one take the 0.5 extra seconds to upvote it.  If you read a question and the person did a good job asking it try upvoting it.

Comment: Thanks for the push. Click-a-thon coming tonight :-D

Comment: Extra Motivation:  You get the Suffrage badge if you make 30 votes in a single day: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/badges/62/suffrage.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Good point well make Saariko. That said, although I've not really seen the need for it yet, don't be afraid to vote down either, though edits and suggestions to fix are preferable—I've already deleted one of my own answers which was shown to not be accurate. Discipline across the site is absolutely key to it's success as it's directly tied to the quality of information contained within.

Also, if you've got a good answer to your question, be sure to **accept** that answer! Credit where it's due is how this game is played :)

Answer (score 15):

Periodically I check the Stack Exchange Notifications:

[image: Vote Up Up Up]

And see *hot questions* from other sites in the network. It seems like this would be a great way to increase the exposure of our SFSE site.

To give an example, the number of visitors to the workplace site is less (by 500 a day) than SFSE, yet the votes cast on their questions is **much** higher.

This post is nothing more than a reminder that voting is free easy and beneficial to the entire community.

Answer (score 4):

Yes I can't stress on this enough. Upvoting helps to give more validity to the answer and also encourages folks to actually answer and obviously gives them credit by improving their reputation. 
I have seen lots of useful answers without upvotes. 
Example: [create new lead from contact screen button pre-populating contact info](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29145/create-new-lead-from-contact-screen-button-pre-populating-contact-info)

I will be voting this up soon but wanted to give an example of this.

Answer (score 4):

Quite a few of the Meta posts are (of course) relating to the absence of upvotes and accepted answers on SFSE. I just wanted to put an answer post here to express that I **don't think** it is inappropriate to add a comment to a tumbleweeding question/conversation prompting a user to upvote or accept an answer (yet, to me, certainly it seems like a taboo thing to do).

I have seen loads of answers, and indeed have a few of them provided by myself where comments (or simple facts and evidence) confirm it is the right answer, but not only has it not been accepted, it's not even got any upvotes!

so - whilst I think it should be fine to chuck a comment on after a "thank you that worked" moment asking the user to accept it... is this actually acceptable behaviour?! And if so, what should the wording be, I'd lean towards "No problem, could you please mark this answer as accepted then so future readers know this is the solution?"

Comment: Yes, I would absolutely consider it acceptable to ask for acceptance if they express gratitude or votes indicate an answer as the clear "winner". Many users are used to other platforms where such functionality is absent, it's a process of habituating.