# Feels wrong to get "Enlightened" badge for simple answers

Tags: discussion

Today I've reached 10 upvotes for one-liner answer to [Creating a user with DML](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3967/creating-a-user-with-dml/3968). 
I know we need to work hard to leave the beta etc etc, I've read [Vote UP Vote UP Vote UP](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71/vote-up-vote-up-vote-up)... but it feels wrong/exaggerated.

Simple question, instant answer, a "Ah ha!" / facepalm moment for the developer, move on. We all probably had similar experience in the past and will make mistakes like that in future. I fail to see what's the difficulty or re-usability value of both the question and the answer though ;) If anything - lesson learned from it could be "*check the data model if it fails in runtime even if it compiles ok*" (and nobody posted such answer so far).

There are just so many more interesting questions & amazing answers here that deserve upvoting. Do I miss something?

Comment: I can withdraw my vote if you want. :-)

Comment: Do it, my point is I probably wouldn't upvote it myself :) It really "does not compute" why it went up so much and so fast :/ and the only explanation I can think of is "beta".

Comment: Herd effect is... But really, the thing is that we all one time or another have banged our heads after a missing :if/'/;/"/else/or/__c etc etc. has appeared after 2-3 hours of search. So yea, it was a simple answer for a question, but take the badge and flash it !!!

Comment: @eyescream - While definitely a simple answer, I upvoted the answer because it is clearly the correct answer.  I generally will vote for the correct answer even if it is not clever or insightful to me.

Comment: It was a good answer, Don't be ashamed, be proud! As I mentioned in my comment on @metadaddy's post this caught me out when I was a new developer, and every new developer I've worked with since

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issues like `Profile`/`ProfileId` are non-intuitive for developers new to the platform, and it's questions/answers like this that folks stumble on via Google, bringing them our way, so I say take the badge and wear it with pride, o enlightened one!

Comment: This really caught me out when I was a new Saleforce developer, it's a really simple answer but a high quality one.